# What do I write in my views.py for it to register a user and redirect it to the new complaint page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Right now, this is how my dashboard looks:

[image]

I don't know how to do this but I need that if a user enters his report number in the enter report number field and clicks on register then the page gets redirected to the add new complaint field but the report number field should already be filled out. It should redirect to this:

[image]

my models.py:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
   input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Complaint
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
           'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report number'}),
           'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event type'}),
           'eventdate': DateInput(),
           'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Problem'}),
           'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 130px;width:760px'}),
           'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Manufacturer Name'}),
           'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Product Code'}),
           'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Brand Name'}),
           'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Exemption'}),
           'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Problem'}),
       }
    
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
       reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
       event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
       if not reportnumber and not event_text:
           raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
       return cleaned_data
```

views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
   count = Complaint.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()
   context = {'count':count}
   return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

template:

```
<div class="col-lg middle middle-con">
        <div class="container mid-pink-con">
            <h1 class="we">We value,</h1>
            <h5 class="txt">Lodge your complaints here <br> and relex, now it's our turn.</h5>

            <input class="search" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder=" Enter Report Number" title="Type in a name">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark register-button">Register</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container mid-white-con">
            <p class="comp-txt">Number of complaints registered on your profile</p>
            <h1 class="header1">{{count}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What should I type in to my views.py??

Comment: to put it out in simple words you want the report number field pre filled in the complaint page right ??

Comment: yes, exactly. when the user puts in the report number in the field above the page should redirect to the add new complaint page and their the report number should be prefilled

Answer (score 0):

I will approach this by,

****1** Sending the report number into the views :**

Once an user enters his report number in the dashboard page, pass the entered report number as an argument to the view that handles the rendering of complaints page...

**2 In the views that renders the complaints page, you can set the initial data's of your form like this**

example :

```
def view(request,report_number): //The report number passed as argument from the Dashboard page
    
    data = {'reportnumber': report_number} // set the reportnumber field of the complaint's form to the request parameter's report_number
    form = ComplaintForm(initial=data)
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'form': form})
```